# How and when can god listen our pray?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, brahma, time, human

The concept of time in Hindu mythology has remarked that one day of god is equal to billions years of human. for example( correct me if wrong)
One day of Brahma = 4.32 billion human years
One year of Brahma = 4.32 billion * 360 (days and nights in a Brahma year) human years
The lifespan of Brahma = 4.32 billion * 360 * 100 human years
by calculation: 1 year of human= 0.00001 Brahma seconds.
so if one prays( via tantra/mantra/yoga etc.) god for 100 year,  this period is 0.001 second of God, then how god listen him and spiritually help him? why is it  not possible that gods  have to neglect us due to his short period of time? Then how (which procedure) do we connect with god?

Answer (score 0):

The calculation of time attributing to Brahma is a Puranic concoction. But, that doesn't mean it to be invalid or otherwise. Accept or deny, a Literature is what it is. Now, coming to the 'time' part of your question.

If we go one step further into older literature, for example Vasista Yoga, you can notice that the same Ramayana (as an event in human time) has happened countless times with slight variations, just like parallel realities. If we go further into the Yajur Vedas, you can see that Rudra is called Kaala (time and space) operating on 3 dimensions which you can relate it to being past, present and future, but it also denotes that time as per Vedas is an exhaustive fire burning with all 3 dimensions in the current moment (trikaagni Kaalya). If we cross-reference this with Vasista Yoga again, then it too agrees that events can be viewed (all 3 dimensions) at the same moment by a witness.

Now, let's step to the practical (reality) sense of current human comprehension, which shows that, God has no business to listen to our prayers or otherwise. Why? when there is an autonomous Karmic cycle (causality) in play there is no need to someone to keep an account externally towards our actions/thoughts. So all accounting is within collaborating with rest of existence. That is why Yoga doesn't base its doctrine on conjecture or any mythical premise, rather on daily methods/tools. It bases itself on implementation of various methods to emulate the 8 limbs of Yoga, and not on God business. With "total Surrender" towards liberation as one of its quickest methods.

So someone famously said, "God doesn't lift his little finger". If not then, 1000 years of brutally massacre, invasions, slaughter, rapes, killings are worse than the literature described hell, could have all been prevented. One can explore Barbar's invasion as an example. Picking few good events, does not justify nor wash away the existence of demonic acts of humans.

So, all events of time (duration) if we consider it as the 4th dimension of creation, to be linear, then the puranic reference is applicable no doubt. Even so, it makes no difference for an omnipotent infinite being that exists beyond this 4th dimension can have any limitation towards listening/knowing its own possibility, no matter how micro that may be.